# There is any way to handle errors with correct status code in NestJS or with GraphQL?

Tags: nestjs, gql

Actually, the GQL validation errors working correctly but when I throw the nestjs error with **Exceptions of nestjs** I don't get proper status code or exact error on the base array or inner objects the actual error found in the dept of the array. And in the browser network tab always show the 200 status even the nestjs throw an error, there is any way to catch the error which is thrown by the nestjs and **correct status** code in browser network tab when catch error?

Answer (score 4):

The Apollo Server constructor accepts a `formatError` function that is run on each error passed back to the client. This can be used to mask errors as well as for logging and the in the NestJS you can use this method in your `GraphQLModule` mostly exists in the `app.module.ts`

```
 GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      ....
      ...
      formatError: (error) => {
        const graphQLFormattedError = {
          message:
            error.extensions?.exception?.response?.message || error.message,
          code:
            error.extensions?.code || "SERVER_ERROR",
          name: error.extensions?.exception?.name || error.name,
        };
        return graphQLFormattedError;
      },
  }),
```

Comment: so how to catch this error on front end side? and how to change the status code there?

Comment: If it's a GraphQL validation error, it will send you the proper status code, and if your throw an error in the Mutation or Query you'll receive HTTP status code `200` but you'll receive the errors array.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this type of problem by throwing grapqhl type error, where you can easily manage message and code.

```
throw new GraphQLError(
  customMessage,
   {
    extensions: {
    code: customCode,
   },
  },
 );
```